# Non-loopy way to create a dynamic mask

Tags: numpy

I am creating a mask based on the values in another array. Is there a non-loopy way to do so?

```py
max_value = 5
num = 10
values = np.random.randint(max_value, size=(num))
mask = np.ones((num, max_value, max_value))
for idx in range(num):
    n = values[idx]
    mask[idx, -n:, -n:] = 0
```

Comment: Sometimes it's better to construct one `advanced indexing` array, instead of the multliple slices.  But that also requires some sort of iteration of the `values`.  That `mask[idx, -n:, -n:]` will have a different shape for each `n`, so you can't do that with one basic indexing call.

Comment: Ahh! I just figured out how to do so :)

Comment: `np.minimum(np.arange(max_value), np.arange(max_value)[:,None]) < max_value - values[:,None,None]`

Comment: That's super pythonic! Thanks :) Do you want to post that in the answers?

Answer (score 1):

Just figured a non-loopy way - (a) create indices and broadcast them across the first two axes, (b) use inequality operation to create zeros and ones, (c) add with it's own transpose to get non-zero values at the masked positions. (caveat - if `low` is 0, it will not work).

```py
max_value = 5
num = 10
values = np.random.randint(low=1, high=max_value, size=(num))
mask = np.ones((num, max_value, max_value), dtype=np.int64)
for idx in range(num):
    n = values[idx]
    mask[idx, -n:, -n:] = 0

# non-loopy 
indices = np.arange(max_value)[None, :].repeat(max_value, 0)
indices = indices[None, :].repeat(num, 0)
partial_mask = np.where(indices < max_value - values[:, None, None], 1, 0)
new_mask = np.where(partial_mask.swapaxes(-1, -2) + partial_mask, 1, 0)

print(np.all(mask == new_mask))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code (mask is bool dtype, may by best use sparse matrices..):

```
mask = np.zeros((num, max_value, max_value), dtype=bool)
mask[np.arange(num),-values,-values]=True
mask=np.cumsum(mask, axis=2, dtype=bool)
mask=~np.cumsum(mask, axis=1,dtype=bool)
```